# iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode? ) Django

Tags: python, django

I have been facing an issue with file upload , so i will be uploading a file on submit , i want to collect the file read the data in it and add it to the database , I am constantly getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vinaykashyap/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/vinaykashyap/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/vinaykashyap/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/vinaykashyap/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vinaykashyap/Desktop/Deploy-Testing2/annotating/views.py", line 244, in UploadAdmin
    next(reader)  # skips header
  File "/Users/vinaykashyap/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 111, in __next__
    self.fieldnames
  File "/Users/vinaykashyap/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 98, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

It will be helpful anyone of you can suggest , how it needs to done .
Thanks in Advance

Views.py

```
def UploadAdmin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         if request.POST.get("action_name") == 'NEXT':
                #  form =  request.FILES['my_uploaded_file'].read()
                 reader = csv.DictReader(request.FILES['my_uploaded_file'].file)
                 next(reader)  # skips header
                 for row in reader:   
                     _, created = NewsItem.objects.get_or_create(
                     headline=row[0],
                     content=row[1],
                     collection=row[2],
                     url=row[3],
                     chunk_id=row[4]
                  )
    return render(request,'annotating/uploadDataAdmin.html')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

at the risk of a bit much magic, I'd do something like:

```
import codecs

column_names = ['headline', 'content', 'collection', 'url', 'chunk_id']

def form_handler(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.FILES['my_uploaded_file']

        # iteratively decode file from bytes to string and interpret as CSV
        reader = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(file, 'utf-8'))

        # skip the header
        next(reader)

        # create items from remaining rows
        for row in reader:
            NewsItem.objects.get_or_create(
                **dict(zip(column_names, row))
            )
```

the important fact is that the `file` is binary and `csv.reader` expects strings, [`codecs.iterdecode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.iterdecode) is a nice way to do that.  if you are sure you have a small amount of data you could just `read` it all in then `decode` the bytes into a string.  for example you might use:

```
  reader = csv.reader(file.read().decode('utf8').splitlines())
```

instead, but I'd suggest using `iterdecode`.  the `column_names` stuff is just a shorthand way of doing what your code was doing